# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.auth.decoraters'

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to create a login and logout page for my sample project and have coded all logic up. The tutorial I was following used the following code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decoraters import login_required


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')

def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':

        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors)

    else:

        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',
                            {'user_form':user_form,
                            'registered':registered })

@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponse("You are logged in!")


@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:

            if user.is_active:

                login(request,user)

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

            else:

                return HttpResponse("Account Not Active")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed")
            print("Username:{} and password: {}".format(username,password))

            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied")
    else:

        return render(request,'basic_app/login.html',{})
```

The error I am getting is this

from django.contrib.auth.decoraters import login_required

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.auth.decoraters'

Comment: It's a spelling mistake : decorators

Comment: thank you! it worked :)

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

Answer (score 0):

You make spelling mistakes while importing the decorators:

**Change:**
`from django.contrib.auth.decoraters import login_required`

**To:**

```html
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```